406 webhook error {"error":"Expected JSON but didn't get it."}
WP6.6.2 civi 5.74.4
406 webhook error {"error":"Expected JSON but didn't get it."}
This is the error message I receive for url https://website/civicrm/mailjetty/webhook
I've had no response to a "mailjetty" post so I'm wondering if anyone could offer any assistance re a webhook errors and how to trouble shoot?

It looks like the extension logs the data it actually receives (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mailjetty/-/blob/1457299f0950c68c0db497ea49141455db5b5b74/CRM/Mailjetty/Page/Webhook.php#L40) so can you look in the civi log?
